# Neater way of writing (Proxy :: Proxy 42) using DataKinds extension

Tags: haskell

I've been using the `DataKinds` extension to pass typelevel `Nat`s to functions in a type safe way, I was just wondering if there was a nicer way of writing:

```
(Proxy :: Proxy 42)
```

for example, is there any extension that will automatically promote the literal `42` to `(Proxy :: Proxy 42)` if the type system sees the argument requires it?

I thought I read of one somewhere but I can't find it now. Getting users to write `(Proxy :: Proxy 42)` is a bit ugly I think.

Answer (score 10):

First, if you enable [`PartialTypeSignatures`](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/partial-type-signatures.html), you can omit a `Proxy`:

```
{-# LANGUAGE PartialTypeSignatures #-}

(Proxy :: _ 42)
```

Second, [`TypeApplications`](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/TypeApplication) in GHC 8 is a neater solution. It lets us supply `forall`-bound arguments explicitly with a `@` prefix:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeApplications, RankNTypes, DataKinds, TypeFamilies #-}

import Data.Proxy
import GHC.TypeLits

foo :: forall (n :: Nat) a. a -> a
foo x = x

bar :: ()
bar = foo @10 () -- apply the type nat literal explicitly
```